# Spark Sql: Loading the file from excel sheet (with extension .xlsx) can not infer the schema of a date-type column properly

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a xlsx file containing date/time filed (My Time) in following format and sample records -

```
5/16/2017 12:19:00 AM
5/16/2017 12:56:00 AM
5/16/2017 1:17:00 PM
5/16/2017 5:26:00 PM
5/16/2017 6:26:00 PM
```

I am reading the xlsx file in following manner: -

```
val inputDF = spark.sqlContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("location","file:///C:/Users/file.xlsx")
    .option("useHeader","true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true")
    .option("inferSchema","true")
    .option("addColorColumns","false")
    .load()
```

When I try to get schema using: -

```
inputDF.printSchema()
```

, I get Double.
Sometimes, even I get the schema as String.
And when I print the data, I get the output as: -

```
------------------
My Time
------------------
42871.014189814814
42871.03973379629
42871.553773148145
42871.72765046296
42871.76887731482
------------------
```

Above output is clearly not correct for the given input.

Moreover, if I convert the xlsx file in csv format and read it, I get the output correctly. Here is the way how I read in csv format: -

```
spark.sqlContext.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .load("file:///C:/Users/file.xlsx")
```

So, any help in this regard, how to infer the correct schema of any column of type date.

Note:- 
Spark version is 2.0.0
Language used is Scala

Comment: those outputs are the correct time.  They are how excel stores date and time in its date serial.  Those values when cell is formatted as date or time or custom will display just date, just time, or some combination there of depending on the customization.  The part before the decimal is the number of days since a given date, January first 1900 or 1905 depending on PC/Mac system if I recall correctly.  The part after the decimal is time or fraction of 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I also have no idea why. However, I suggest you set that "inferSchema" as "false" and then structure yours.